# Textbox warning for large queries with Django

Tags: python, django, webserver

I'm using Django to create a website for a project.  The user fills out a form, then I run some queries with this data and display the results on another page.  Currently it's a two page site.

I want to warn the user if their query result data is very large.  Say if a user ends up getting 1000 rows in the results table, I want to warn the user that queries of this size might take a long time to load.  I imagine that between the form page and the results page, I could make a popup textbox that displays the warning.  I could have this box show if the query object size is greater than 1000.

Does Django have a method for me implementing this?  How can I get this textbox to appear before the result page template is shown?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, query object has the method like this. It is simply:
   query.count()

Comment: I know how to manipulate objects.  I don't know how to make the textbox appear before the result page template is shown.

Comment: Undrestood. Django itself doesn't have the machanism like this. You should play with javascript and ajax I think first to check how big the resutl will be next to show the popup and list result.

Comment: maybe you should think about simple pagination?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think django has a function that will do this.  You could easily do this, if you wanted to, using django and javascript though.

Loading a site with 1000 results really isn't that many.  If the number of results is affecting performance, [paginate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) them.

I think it might be a bit cleaner to just load the results page, directly, with either:

1. paginated results
2. no results and have an ajax request fetch results after the page is loaded, so the page doesn't lag while loading all results

What will your user think of an intermediarary popup? I belive to maximize their expereince, load the page in the fastest least intrusive way possible